# How to preform a component action rather than a route action in ember-file-upload

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using the package 
https://github.com/tim-evans/ember-file-upload

In their example, they call a route action to upload an image

```
             onfileadd=(route-action "uploadImage")}}
```

However I would like to instead call a component action

I tried doing

```
                 onfileadd="uploadImage"}}
```

and added the action in component:

```
uploadImage: function (file) {
  console.log(file);
  let self = this;
  RSVP.cast(Ember.$.get(ENV.APP.API_HOST + "/v1/teams/signed_url/")).then(function (response) {
    return file.upload(response.url, {
      data: response.credentials
    });
  }).then(function (response) {
    self.set('url', response.headers.Location);
  });
},
```

But I got the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uploadImage' of undefined

The action works as expected if I move it to route, but I need to update the correct properties in the component (that do not exist in the route)

Any idea what I can do to change that to a component function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`action`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.16/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/action?anchor=action) helper:

```
onfileadd=(action "uploadImage")}}
```

Also make sure that `uploadImage` is within the `actions` hash in your component:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  // ...
  actions: {
    uploadImage() { // <-- make sure this is inside the actions hash
      // ...
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: sorry I did not share the whole code, it was within the actions hash comment

Adding action helper worked !

Comment: @MohamadZein glad to help mate :)